# Why custom 404 page not working with Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I'm using flask to manage my website, I'm trying to includes a simple 404 page error, but I keep getting the plain one from flask. Here is my code:

flask app

```
@views.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return render_template('errors/404.html'), 404
```

html

```
{% with title="404 Not Found" %}
{% include "head.html" %}
{% endwith %}

<body>
    <h1>404 Page not found</h1>
</body>

</html> ### I need to include the </html> tag because it's in the head.
```

However I'm getting this:

[URL not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cJ3x.png)

Comment: Can you share your complete code from the flask app that would give more insight into your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have registered the error handler with `views`, I presume you are working with blueprints. If this assumption is correct, please note the last paragraph in the "Handling" section:

> Handlers registered on the blueprint take precedence over those registered globally on the application, assuming a blueprint is handling the request that raises the exception. However, the b**lueprint cannot handle 404 routing errors because the 404 occurs at the routing level before the blueprint can be determined**.

To achieve the desired behaviour, register this error handler with the "app" returned by the `Flask(__name__)` initialization.

Comment: Thanks, Magnun, I moved the handler to the app itself as @Gregory Sky suggested and it is fixed. But it's good to know why it happened

Answer (score 0):

Is it just me, or should you change

```
@views.errorhandler(404)
```

to

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
```

Have a look at the original docs: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/errorhandling/

Comment: I'm using views cause I'm using Blueprints, but I'll try directly from the app

Comment: Thank you very much, I moved it to the app itself and it works now.